# Randomly sampling and averaging data in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, average, subset, random

I have a 200x200 matrix containing count information.  I would like to randomly sample a 5 row x 5 column subset within my matrix and take the average of the counts within this subset.  I want to do this 8 times randomly throughout my matrix (so maybe use a for-loop?) and then take the averages of these 8. I also need to use restrictions so that the random number generator doesn't sample at the very edge of my matrix.

I am new to R and programming in general, so a push in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Is this sampling with replacements? Are the subsets allowed to overlap.

Comment: This is not sampling with replacements.  Yes the subsets are allowed to overlap.  I want to randomly sample a 5x5 portion of my matrix and find the average of that 5x5 portion.  I want to do this 8 times and then take the average of the averages from the 5x5 portions.  Sorry if this is confusing. And thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
# an example 10x10 matrix
mat <- matrix(1:100, 10)
nc <- ncol(mat) # number of columns
nr <- nrow(mat) # number of rows

size <- 5 # size of the subset matrix
nmat <- 8 # number of submatrices

# sample indices of submatrices
set.seed(1)
idxc <- sample(seq(2, nc - size), size = nmat, replace = TRUE)
idxr <- sample(seq(2, nr - size), size = nmat, replace = TRUE)

# create a list of 8 submatrices
res <- mapply(function(x, y) mat[seq(x, x + size - 1), seq(y, y + size - 1)],
              idxr, idxc, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# calculate the average of the averages
mean(unlist(res))
# [1] 53.875
```

Comment: The first part works great! Thank you!  For the averaging though,  I would like to find the average of the counts in the 5x5 subset (1 number).  I would like to do this for all 8 different subsets.  I would then like to find the average of these 8 subsets (instead of finding the average of the different cell values). This will give me 1 number at the end.

Comment: Is there a way to get the code to randomly sample different parts of the matrix every time I run it?  Currently, it gives me the same answer each time I run it.

Comment: @MaryR Do not run `set.seed(1)`. It resets the random number generator to a certain state. It is not necessary for the approach. I used it for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that assumes you're always pulling out a square. (ie, the rows/columns are right beside each other).

```
y <- matrix(round(rep(runif(200),200)*100),ncol=200,nrow=200)

sq <- seq(1,196,1) 
blocks <- sample(sq,8) # no replacements of squares

mean(
  sapply(blocks, 
    function(x) mean(y[x:(4+x),x:(4+x)])
  )
)
```